# Meteor.js on Synology NAS

Tags: meteor, nas

Is it possible to deploy a meteor-app to a Synology NAS and run it from there? If so, how?

I guess I need a node.js server to run on my NAS, but I do not know what to do when it is up and running.

Answer (score 3):

Since the Synology NAS is built ontop of linux so you could meteor running on it.

Because some of Synology's NAS units use ARM cpu's you would need to compile meteor for ARM (meaning its dependencies such as MongoDB and Node, all of which should be possible).

Have a look at http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/What_kind_of_CPU_does_my_NAS_have to determine if your nas' CPU is x86 or ARM. If it is ARM you'll have to build the binaries from source. If its x86 you could probably just run `curl https://install.meteor.com | sh`

Have a look at https://github.com/meteor/meteor#slow-start-for-developers to build a dev bundle on your
unit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My NAS' CPU is of the ARM kind of architecture which is by default unsupported by meteor even though I try to make a new build. Anyways by the help of Google searches I have managed to start compiling a new bundle but currently it fails due to some libthread.so error I haven't figured yet.
Whenever I succeed (if I do) I will try to do a writeup on the process...

Answer (score 0):

Meteor can also be deployed as a normal node.JS Application with meteor deploy or you can use demeteorizer (https://www.npmjs.com/package/demeteorizer)

For details please check here: https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html